# Finding records based on different fields/columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a database that has stored information of some users.
I know for example: `User.find(1)` will return the user with id:1

What should I call to find a user by email? I searched a lot but could not find anything.

I also tried `User.find(:email => "xyz@abc.com")` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

```
User.find_by_email("abc@xyz.com")
```

Must check these two post from railscast (For rails3)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Just to add something, there's also a [rails guide on queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). And [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) is shown that the `find_by_*` is dynamically available.

Answer (score 2):

You can also query

```
User.where("email = ?", "abc@xyz.com").first
```

Comment: This is a misuse of ActiveRecord. You should use `User.where(email: 'abc@xyz.com')`.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance you just registered a user and what to find this specific user and retrieve all the user data through the instance,

1. You want to store it in a session[:current_user] = @user
2. @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
3. You want to do this in your create method in your users controller.
4. Now you have access to this new user instance which will be helpful for times when you want them to have a profile page ready for them.
5. Hope it wasn't too off topic, and if so, hope this helps with your future projects! Good Luck!

---

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you have a tip you want to share, and that's great, but it seems like it should be on a different question. It doesn't seem like an "answer" that matches this question. Stack Overflow tries to keep a quite tight match between questions and answers. You can even ask your own question and answer it yourself if you like.